# Принцип работы Group из pygame.sprite

Tags: python-3.x

Недавно начал изучать Питон, синтаксис выучил, теперь разбираюсь в Pygame. Не особо понял про класс `Group` из модуля `pygame.sprite`.

Допустим, есть класс `Bullet`, в котором есть метод `update()`, и я создал группу `bullets` на основе класса `Group` (`bullets = Group()`). Прочитал, что у класса `Group` есть метод `update()`, который вызывает метод `update()` из класса `Bullet` (если мы создаем группу для работы с классом `Bullet`) для каждого спрайта в группе `bullets`.

Так вот, хотел спросить, если у нас есть несколько импортированных модулей, в каждом из которых есть класс, в котором есть метод `update()`, то как понять, что команда `bullets.update()` вызовет метод `update()` именно из нужного нам класса?

Надеюсь, что вы поймете о чем я хотел сказать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Созданная вами группа является пустой, и уж тем более она ничего не знает про какие там объекты типа Bullet. Да и не путайте, метод `Group.update()` вызывает `Sprite.update()` у всех **объектов в группе**, ни про какие классы он не знает.

```
# создали группу
bullets = Group()

# создали экземпляры спрайтов
bullet1 = Bullet(*параметры*)
bullet2 = Bullet(*параметры*)
bullet3 = Bullet(*параметры*)

# поместили нужные спрайты 1 и 2 в группу
bullets.add(bullet1, bullet2)

# в игровом цикле вызываем update у нашей группы
# update() будет вызван только у bullet1 и bullet2
# которые мы вручную и добавили в группу
bullets.update()
```

Объект `bullet3` не был добавлен в группу, а значит и update группы его никак не затронет.

Comment: понял, спасибо,но, все же, я не понял, а метод Sprite.update() где задавать?)

Comment: я создаю класс Bullet на основе класса Sprite, в классе Bullet пишу метод update(), но этот метод же не считается как Sprite.update(), верно?

Comment: @ИльяРоманов, почему он не считается? Вы перегружаете `Sprite.update()` при наследовании, так что `Bullet.update()` будет вызван в группе.

Comment: Cпасибо, что вы мне отвечаете))     Spite.update()     означает что мы вызываем метод update() из класса, который наследует от класса Sprite?  Извините, если честно, я не особо понимаю) Я еще писал о том, что если есть несколько классов, которые созданы на основе класса Sprite и в каждом из этих классов есть метод update(), то как понять, что метод Group.update() вызовет то, что нам надо?

Comment: @ИльяРоманов, когда вы наследуетесь от класса `Sprite` и перегружаете метод `Sprite.update()`, всегда будет вызываться метод, перегруженный вами. Довольно трудно пояснить эту концепцию в комментариях (лучше обратиться к гуглу на тему наследования и вызова перегруженных методов), если вкратце, это сделано для того, чтобы вы могли хранить в группе не только объекты типа `Bullet`, но и любые другие объекты, чьи типы унаследованы от класса `Sprite`. И при этом у всех них, вне зависимости от их типа, будет вызван `update()`.

Comment: Видимо это надо вживую объяснять, потому что я не особо понимаю, но спасибо вам за то, что попытались объяснить) Но все же сделаю последнюю попытку) Возможно, я объясню сейчас не особо корректно, но надеюсь, что вы поймете. Допустим, мы добавляем в группу экземпляр, созданный на основе класса Bullet (в этом классе есть метод update), получается, что при вызове Group.update() , Python ищет метод update() в классе Bullet, т.к. экземпляр создан на основе именно этого класса? Это так работает?

Comment: @ИльяРоманов, вам нужно понять, как работает наследование, повторюсь, в комментариях это невозможно за пару строк описать :)