# Одинаковы ли коды по смыслу?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Недавно начал учить питон, сейчас добрался до pygame. Хотел бы спросить, эти два кода делают же одно и то же?

`bullets` - экземпляр класса `Group`, содержащий в себе объекты типа `Bullet`, унаследованные от базового класса `Sprite`.

Первый код:

```
for bullet in bullets.sprites(): 
    bullet.update()
```

Второй код:

```
bullets.update()
```

Comment: Зависит от того, что делают функции update(). В общем случае - нет.

Comment: функция update() в классе Bullet перемещает пулю вверху по экрану. Почему в общем случае - нет?

Comment: Да, это одно и то же. Вопрос аналогичен вашему предыдущему вопросу. Повторюсь и здесь - прочитайте хотя бы базовые вещи о наследовании, без него вы не сможете писать такие сложные вещи, как игры.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Принцип работы Group из pygame.sprite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927468/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%bf-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-group-%d0%b8%d0%b7-pygame-sprite)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker так эти коды одинаковые по смыслу? просто тот, кто ответил выше, сказал, что они разные) Я думаю, что они одинаковые, и чтобы точно убедиться, написал сюда.

Comment: Вам сказали, что в **общем случае** они разные, `Group` для этого и нужен, чтобы вызывать `update()` у всех элементов, которые хранятся в группе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Топаем в документацию pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html)

Смотрим, что там написано про `Group`:

> A simple **container** for Sprite objects...

Смотрим документацию метода `Group.update`:

> **Calls the update() method on all Sprites in the Group**. The base Sprite
>   class has an update method that takes any number of arguments and does
>   nothing. The arguments passed to Group.update() will be passed to each
>   Sprite.

Вызывает `update()` для всех объектов типа `Sprite` или его наследников. Из чего следует, что данный код:

```
for _sprite in _group.sprites(): 
    _sprite.update()
```

Эквивалентен этому коду:

```
_group.update()
```

---

Данный контейнер для того и сделан, чтобы вы не писали никакие циклы или, что еще хуже, вручную не прописывали `draw()` и `update()` каждого своего видимого объекта. Более того, как указано во все той же документации, вам ничто не мешает унаследоваться у `Group` и сделать свой контейнер со специфичным поведением.

Comment: только сейчас зашел на сайт) все понял, спасибо)